# C++: get native dll dependencies without loading it in process

Tags: c++, dll, portable-executable, loadlibrary, systems-programming

I need to programmatically obtain DLL's dependencies list. Here is how I'm trying to solve this task:

```cpp
BSTR GetDllDependencies(const wchar_t* dllPath)
{
    std::wstring dependencies;

    struct LibDeleter
    {
        typedef HMODULE pointer;
        void operator()(HMODULE hMod) { FreeLibrary(hMod); }
    };

    auto hModRaw = LoadLibraryExW(dllPath, NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES); //(*)nullptr nere
    auto hMod = std::unique_ptr<HMODULE, LibDeleter>();

    auto imageBase = (DWORD_PTR)hMod.get();

    auto header = ImageNtHeader(hMod.get());
    auto importRVA = header->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
    auto importTable = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(DWORD_PTR)(importRVA + imageBase);

    while (importRVA && importTable->OriginalFirstThunk)
    {
        auto importedModuleName = (char*)(DWORD_PTR)(importTable->Name + imageBase);
        dependencies
            .append(importedModuleName, importedModuleName + std::strlen(importedModuleName))
            .append(L",");

        importTable++;
    }

    auto result = SysAllocString(dependencies.c_str());

    return result;
}
```

It works. But, as you can see it loads the DLL into process. And I ran into a problem in this place: `LoadLibraryEx` returns `nullptr` if process already has loaded DLL with the same name.

[image: nullptr]

I'm not sure is it allowed to load two DLLs with the same name (but different location) into the same process? I believe yes. Then why `LoadLibraryEx` returns `nullptr`? Is it possible to somehow get DLLs dependencies without loading DLL?

Comment: You need to parse imports section of PE (Portable Executable) file (that is .dll or .exe).

Comment: As Mentioned in the documentation [`DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` is deprecated and may not be supported in all versions of windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll need to load as a datafile instead.

Comment: `LoadLibraryEx returns nullptr if process already has loaded DLL with the same name` this is not true

Comment: `Then why LoadLibraryEx returns nullptr` - then why you not call `GetLastError` or `RtlGetLastNtStatus` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution use manual navigation within DLL file. The basis of the solution is `RVAtoRAW` function which translates RVA addresses to RAW ones (addresses within file).

```cpp
//Defining in which section particular RVA address actually located (section number)
DWORD RVAtoRAW(DWORD rva, PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeaderRAW, WORD sectionsCount)
{
    int sectionNo;
    for (sectionNo = 0; sectionNo < sectionsCount; ++sectionNo)
    {
        auto sectionBeginRVA = sectionHeaderRAW[sectionNo].VirtualAddress;
        auto sectionEndRVA = sectionBeginRVA + sectionHeaderRAW[sectionNo].Misc.VirtualSize;
        if (sectionBeginRVA <= rva && rva <= sectionEndRVA)
            break;
    }
    //Evaluating RAW address from section & RVA
    auto sectionRAW = sectionHeaderRAW[sectionNo].PointerToRawData;
    auto sectionRVA = sectionHeaderRAW[sectionNo].VirtualAddress;
    auto raw = sectionRAW + rva - sectionRVA;

    return raw;
}

BSTR GetDllDependencies(const wchar_t* dllPath)
{
    auto buffer = ReadFile(dllPath);
    if (buffer.empty())
        return SysAllocString(L"");

    //RAW - offset from beginnig of the file (absolute "address" within file)
    auto baseRAW = buffer.data();
    auto dosHeaderRAW = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)baseRAW;
    auto peHeaderRAW = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(baseRAW + dosHeaderRAW->e_lfanew);
    auto sectionHeaderRAW = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(baseRAW + dosHeaderRAW->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));

    auto sectionsCount = peHeaderRAW->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

    //RVA - Relative Virtual Address - relative (to ImageBase) address within virtual address space of the process which loads this DLL
    auto importTableRVA = peHeaderRAW->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
    auto importTableRAW = RVAtoRAW(importTableRVA, sectionHeaderRAW, sectionsCount);
    auto importTable = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(baseRAW + importTableRAW);

    std::wstring dependencies;
    while (importTableRVA && importTable->OriginalFirstThunk)
    {
        auto nameRAW = RVAtoRAW(importTable->Name, sectionHeaderRAW, sectionsCount);

        auto importedModuleName = (char*)(DWORD_PTR)(nameRAW + baseRAW);
        dependencies
            .append(importedModuleName, importedModuleName + std::strlen(importedModuleName))
            .append(L",");

        importTable++;
    }

    auto result = SysAllocString(dependencies.c_str());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find this article by Matt Pietrek interesting. In particular, take a look at the `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` array in the paragraph *"PE File Imports"*.

> [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)